# openssl_pkey_new returns false on windows php

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp, php-openssl

I am using x64, PHP 7.0.4, Apache 2.4. I am trying to create a private and public key

```php
$config = array(
    "digest_alg" => "sha512",
    "private_key_bits" => 1024,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
);

// Create the private and public key
$res = openssl_pkey_new($config);
var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations());
var_dump(openssl_error_string());exit;
```

i get this output

```php
array(8) {
  ["default_cert_file"]=>
  string(36) "c:/openssl-1.0.2e-win32/ssl/cert.pem"
  ["default_cert_file_env"]=>
  string(13) "SSL_CERT_FILE"
  ["default_cert_dir"]=>
  string(33) "c:/openssl-1.0.2e-win32/ssl/certs"
  ["default_cert_dir_env"]=>
  string(12) "SSL_CERT_DIR"
  ["default_private_dir"]=>
  string(35) "c:/openssl-1.0.2e-win32/ssl/private"
  ["default_default_cert_area"]=>
  string(27) "c:/openssl-1.0.2e-win32/ssl"
  ["ini_cafile"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ini_capath"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

It results in:

```
string(51) "error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process"
```

in which file i should make changes, and where can i find correct files and paths?

best regards